# Heroku Procfile.windows behaving oddly

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm attempting to deploy my Django app to Heroku. I'm working on Windows but when I name my procfile `Procfile.windows` I get a

```py
Procfile declares types -> (none)
```

error. When I just name it `Procfile` I get a

```py
 bash: py: command not found
```

Here's the file:

```sh
web: py manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I tried with `python` instead of `py` and got

```
Build succeeded
2020-09-01T06:48:12.435733+00:00 app[web.1]: Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2020-09-01T06:48:12.436952+00:00 app[web.1]: Performing system checks...
2020-09-01T06:48:12.436953+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-01T06:48:12.883911+00:00 app[web.1]: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
2020-09-01T06:48:13.163963+00:00 app[web.1]: September 01, 2020 - 06:48:13
2020-09-01T06:48:13.164126+00:00 app[web.1]: Django version 3.1, using settings 'lunaSite.settings'
2020-09-01T06:48:13.164127+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
2020-09-01T06:48:13.164128+00:00 app[web.1]: Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2020-09-01T06:48:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-09-01T06:48:13.767832+00:00 app[web.1]: Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2020-09-01T06:48:13.768157+00:00 app[web.1]: Performing system checks...
2020-09-01T06:48:13.768163+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-01T06:48:14.101794+00:00 app[web.1]: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
2020-09-01T06:48:14.264505+00:00 app[web.1]: September 01, 2020 - 06:48:14
2020-09-01T06:48:14.264609+00:00 app[web.1]: Django version 3.1, using settings 'lunaSite.settings'
2020-09-01T06:48:14.264609+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
2020-09-01T06:48:14.264610+00:00 app[web.1]: Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2020-09-01T06:49:08.160313+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-09-01T06:49:08.188765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-09-01T06:49:08.320546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-09-01T06:49:10.304145+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-09-01T06:49:10.328270+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-09-01T06:49:10.419954+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-09-01T06:49:10.489203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-01T06:49:12.722670+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lunawebsite.herokuapp.com request_id=04a84a44-53b8-409d-b2ef-4403c8aabb67 fwd="73.69.214.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-01T06:49:13.347117+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lunawebsite.herokuapp.com request_id=8c3c75d6-e6b7-48c6-8cc5-1540c1133ea7 fwd="73.69.214.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-01T06:49:13.628310+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lunawebsite.herokuapp.com request_id=c67d8f0e-c8c8-4212-a042-db9e3d58c64e fwd="73.69.214.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-01T06:49:22.655764+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lunawebsite.herokuapp.com request_id=c4046069-581e-4315-8b4d-4212298559fd fwd="73.69.214.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-01T06:49:22.778778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lunawebsite.herokuapp.com request_id=3c15c236-1945-4c3e-a047-9806f8ce6255 fwd="73.69.214.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

What's the problem here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: py is unknown, can you try web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: I tried that. I said I tried in the question and it worked except it timed out and crashed

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> bash: py: command not found
> ```

That's correct, `py` *won't* be found. `py.exe` only exists on Windows, and Heroku doesn't run Windows. And the file *should* be called `Procfile`, not `Procfile.windows`.

Use `python` instead:

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

You might also want to consider using [`django-heroku`](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku), which helps to set a bunch of Heroku-specific stuff up in Django projects.

Now that that's out of the way, there are a few other issues here:

- You don't get to pick your port on Heroku. [One will be assigned to you dynamically via the `PORT` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers). This is the cause of the boot timeout errors you mentioned above.
- [`manage.py runserver` shouldn't be used in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

  > DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

You need a proper web server. Gunicorn is a common choice, but it doesn't work on Windows. If you want to use it anyway, add `gunicorn` to your dependencies and use something like this in your `Procfile`, replacing `<project_name>` with the name of your project:

```
web: gunicorn <project_name>.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

This won't work locally, though. If you want something that will work on Windows and Heroku, take a look at Waitress and uWSGI.