# Heroku Flask: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I have been trying to make a blog app in Flask. Everything works fine in local host. But when  try to push to Heroku, it gives me the dreaded H10 error. Googling tells me to fix procfile and add gunicorn in requirements.txt. I have done both, in fact, I have tried everything I could, but nothing is working.

Here is the error -

```
2022-02-25T18:48:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bsse1013@iit.du.ac.bd
2022-02-25T18:48:51.393695+00:00 app[api]: Deploy cffc4591 by user bsse1013@iit.du.ac.bd
2022-02-25T18:48:51.393695+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user bsse1013@iit.du.ac.bd
2022-02-25T18:48:53.004126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-25T18:48:56.836379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:7388 app:app --log-file=log.txt`
2022-02-25T18:48:58.760393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-25T18:48:58.462336+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-02-25T18:48:58.462406+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2022-02-25T18:48:58.462730+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.sleep()
2022-02-25T18:48:58.462746+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
2022-02-25T18:48:58.467812+00:00 app[web.1]:     ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2022-02-25T18:48:58.467839+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468120+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468136+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468414+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468535+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468584+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468585+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468585+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468603+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468619+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468786+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468800+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468967+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2022-02-25T18:48:58.468989+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
2022-02-25T18:48:58.469188+00:00 app[web.1]:     super().run()
2022-02-25T18:48:58.469203+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2022-02-25T18:48:58.469355+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2022-02-25T18:48:58.469369+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2022-02-25T18:48:58.469563+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2022-02-25T18:48:58.469577+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2022-02-25T18:48:58.470213+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2022-02-25T18:48:58.470230+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2022-02-25T18:48:58.470497+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2022-02-25T18:48:58.470511+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2022-02-25T18:48:58.471136+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2022-02-25T18:48:58.471153+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2022-02-25T18:48:58.471920+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2022-02-25T18:48:58.472025+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2022-02-25T18:48:58.664689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-25T18:49:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-02-25T18:49:08.798373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/register" host=flask-blog-10.herokuapp.com request_id=78a36854-c690-4886-926e-da21b23c664b fwd="37.120.137.77" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-25T18:49:09.276608+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=flask-blog-10.herokuapp.com request_id=25a7f92c-f1a9-415e-8254-bf66a128fde7 fwd="37.120.137.77" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my Procfile:
`web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app --log-file=log.txt`

Also tried this with Procfile:
`web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app`

Also tried this with Procfile:
`web: gunicorn app:app`
I made sure there is no trailing whitespace in procfile.

requirement.txt (Yes, I have gunicorn here):

```
decorator==4.4.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
gunicorn==20.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
json5==0.9.5
jsonschema==3.2.0
mysqlclient==2.1.0
pymongo==3.11.3
requests==2.25.1
requests-html==0.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.31
Werkzeug==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.0
```

runtime.txt:
`python-3.9.1`

Here is the app.py file -

```
from flask import Flask
import auth
import blog
from db import initialize_db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'super secret key'

app.register_blueprint(blog.bp)
app.add_url_rule('/', endpoint='index')

app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
initialize_db()
```

This is tearing me up. Please help!

Edit: Apparently the gitignore file was the root of all troubles. What is wrong with it?
[Gitignore file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJq0G.png)

Comment: Please show your `app.py` file

Comment: (Side note, don't use `--log-file=log.txt` on Heroku. You want your logs to go to stdout or stderr so they are included in Heroku's log stream. But that isn't causing your current problem.)

Comment: Thanks @Chris! I have added the code from app.py.

Comment: Oops, I missed this earlier: In your `Procfile` you are using port 5000. You don't get to pick your port on Heroku. Let me find a suitable duplicate.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/67590324/354577 and my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/q/63682755/354577

Comment: In the end, the gitignore file was the problem. Could you please take a look at why it was causing the problem? @Chris
I have added the edit on post.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). You shared code correctly before, I'm not sure why you'd switch to screenshots now. "In the end, the gitignore file was the problem"—what makes you say that?

Comment: Because after deleting gitignore and then pushing, to Heroku, the error has gone away and the app is working. @chris

Comment: If that is all you did, it definitely didn't fix anything. Something else caused this (almost certainly the fact that you were not using Heroku's `PORT` environment variable, as I described in previous comments). Deleting your `.gitignore` is a bad idea. That file is there for a reason.